# Xamarin forms Data binding on checkbox

Tags: c#, xamarin, data-binding

I tried this code for some reason upon clicking the checkbox it doesnt change the value of the behind.

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68534028/how-to-bind-data-to-the-bindableproperty-in-xamarin-forms) post but didnt fully understand how it works.

Xaml

```
<CheckBox Color="#9E9D9B" 
          x:Name="red"
          IsChecked="{Binding RedBool}"/>
```

Code Behind

```
public static readonly BindableProperty RedBox = BindableProperty.Create(
propertyName: nameof(RedBool),
returnType: typeof(bool),
declaringType: typeof(NewCraft),
defaultValue: false,
defaultBindingMode: BindingMode.TwoWay,
propertyChanged: changedProperty);

private static void changedProperty(BindableObject bindable, object oldValue, object newValue)
{
    var redBind = (NewCraft)bindable;
    redBind.RedBool = (bool)newValue;
}

public bool RedBool
{
    get => (bool)GetValue(RedBox);
    set => SetValue(RedBox, value);
}
```

Comment: your link is broken.  Regardless, why are you creating a `BindableProperty`?  That is not necessary, all you need is normal `public bool property`.  Also, have you set the `BindingContext` of the page?  Bindings do not work without a `BindingContext`

Comment: Because its an component on another page thats being imported so this in my eyes seems like the way to do it, Is there a better way? where and how would i set the bindingContext? i have `this.BindingContext = red;` in the constructor

Comment: that doesn't make sense, because `red` doesn't have a `RedBool` property.  I'd try `BindingContext = this;`